# Starting new subactivity clears all data from ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have an Android application with a settings activity, that allows me to edit settings and a main activity with a listview. I also have a separate help activity. When I go to either the settings or help and return to the main activity, the data from the listview is cleared... 
It has to be downloaded from the internet each time it load and be parsed, so I want to know if it's possible to no have it cleared each time...

Thanks

Comment: In what method are you creating and initializing the list?

Comment: The list is initialized when a menu button is pressed (refresh), this starts a asynctask, setting the content of the listview custom adapter

Comment: Ok, but more specifically, what do you do in onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop, onDestroy, onRestart?  Something in one of those is likely the culprit.

Comment: In the onCreate, I just inflate the layout... I haven't touched the other methods. I should override pause and resume?

Comment: Well, put a breakpoint in onCreate and see if it is getting called again after viewing your help activity.

Comment: Could you please post your code, or an example? It is near impossible to see the problem by just fishing for potential issues.

Comment: This is my main class... http://pastebin.com/hc42QJc5

Comment: Post your manifest too, please.  (And post it here, in this page.)  Basically, your activity is getting destroyed when viewing help.  So, when you close Help, the main activity gets created from scratch.  Either your Help activity is very large, thus needing to reclaim memory from the main activity, or you have some setting that is forcing the activity to destroy.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eYG1NZ3p this is my manifest file. I don't think my help activity is too big... It's just loading some strings...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the main activity is getting destroyed.

Here's one solution that will work, though.  Create a subclass, MyApp, from Application and load your adapter there, during its onCreate.  (There is exactly one instance of Application and it is a good place to keep global data.)

In your main activity's onCreate, create the list view and fetch the adapter from MyApp.  Then you will only be doing the expensive part (creating the adapter) once.

Comment: Found it! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is; set the launchmode to singleTop for the main activity in the android manifest xml file... More info here; http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode